# laravel reloading different content when checking different radio button

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables, laravel-5

i'm working on a page having two radio buttons and a table filled with data from the controller. the data shown in the table are from two different categories.
now i want to make sure that when user chooses a different radio button it displays just the category of this button not both categories
here is my try

this is the Controller method that retrieves the data

```
public function Data(){

    $data = App\Equations::get();


    return array('aaData'=>$data);
}
```

and here how i receive it in the view using Ajax

```
var table = $('#table-active').DataTable({
        responsive: {
        details: {
           type: 'column',
           target: -1
           }
        },
        ajax:{"url" : "datatblejson",type:"get",data:{_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}},
        buttons: {
            dom: {
                button: {
                    className: 'btn btn-default'
                }
            },
            buttons: [
                 {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    text: '<i class=icon-loop3></i>',
                    className: 'btn btn-default',
                    action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url:'datatblejson', type: 'get', data: {_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}    
                        });
                        $('#table-active').DataTable().ajax.reload();

                    }
                },
                {extend: 'copy',text: '<i title="Copy" class="icon-copy3"></i>'},
                {extend: 'csv' ,text: '<i title="Export to CSV sheet." class="icon-file-spreadsheet"></i>'},
                {extend: 'excel' ,text: '<i title="Export to excel sheet." class="icon-file-excel"></i>'},
                {extend: 'pdf' , text: '<i title="Export to PDF file." class="icon-file-pdf"></i>'},
                {extend: 'print', text: '<i title="Print" class="icon-printer"></i>'},
                {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    text: '<i class="icon-three-bars"></i> <span class="caret"></span>',
                    className: 'btn bg-blue btn-icon'
                }

            ]
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {
                className: 'control',
                orderable: false,
                targets:   -1
            }],
        deferRender: true,
        columns:[
        {"render": function ( type, full, data, meta ) {
            return '<a href="#" title="Open profile" class="profile" >'+data.name+'</a>';
        }},
        {"render": function ( type, full, data, meta ) {
            return '<input type="text" name='+data.id+' value='+data.value+'>';
        }},

        { "data": null, "defaultContent":'<center><ul class="icons-list"><li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-menu9"></i></a><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">' +
         '<li><a href="#" class="history" ><i class="icon-file-stats"></i> Timeline</a></li>' +
         '<li><a href="#" class="profile" ><i class="icon-user"></i> Profile</a></li>' +
         '<li><a href="#" class="disconnect"><i class=" icon-file-eye"></i> Disconnect </a></li>' +
         '<li><a href="#" class="suspend"><i class=" icon-file-eye"></i> Suspend </a></li>' +
         '</ul> </li> </ul></center>'}
         //{ "data":null,"defaultContent":"" }
        ]
    });
```

and here is the form that contains the two radio buttons that i want to change table content when checked

```
<form action="{{url('update_price')}}" method="get" id="update">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h5 class="panel-title">Update Prices NOW!</h5>
            </div>



            <div class="row" style="margin-left: 5%">
              <h3>Please Choose a Category</h3>
              <input class="radio" id="radio-1" name="rd" type="radio" checked value="engineer">
              <label tabindex="4" for="radio-1" class="radio-label">Engineer</label>
              <br />
              <input class="radio" id="radio-2" name="rd" type="radio" value="user">
              <label tabindex="5" for="radio-2" class="radio-label">Normal User</label>
              <br />

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
            <table class="table" width="100%" id="table-active">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Cost</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <button id="button" style="margin-left: 45%;back"></button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with some function in jquery to get again the data when the radio button clicked? and adding a category parameter to the ajax request..

Something like this:

```
$('.radio').on('click', function(){
  var table = $('#table-active').DataTable({
    responsive: {
    details: {
       type: 'column',
       target: -1
       }
    },
    ajax:{"url" : "datatblejson",type:"get",data:{_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}},
    buttons: {
        dom: {
            button: {
                className: 'btn btn-default'
            }
        },
        buttons: [
             {
                extend: 'colvis',
                text: '<i class=icon-loop3></i>',
                className: 'btn btn-default',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'datatblejson', type: 'get', data: {_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), category: 'id_category'}    
                    });
                    $('#table-active').DataTable().ajax.reload();

                }
            },
            {extend: 'copy',text: '<i title="Copy" class="icon-copy3"></i>'},
            {extend: 'csv' ,text: '<i title="Export to CSV sheet." class="icon-file-spreadsheet"></i>'},
            {extend: 'excel' ,text: '<i title="Export to excel sheet." class="icon-file-excel"></i>'},
            {extend: 'pdf' , text: '<i title="Export to PDF file." class="icon-file-pdf"></i>'},
            {extend: 'print', text: '<i title="Print" class="icon-printer"></i>'},
            {
                extend: 'colvis',
                text: '<i class="icon-three-bars"></i> <span class="caret"></span>',
                className: 'btn bg-blue btn-icon'
            }

        ]
    },
    columnDefs: [
        {
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets:   -1
        }],
    deferRender: true,
    columns:[
    {"render": function ( type, full, data, meta ) {
        return '<a href="#" title="Open profile" class="profile" >'+data.name+'</a>';
    }},
    {"render": function ( type, full, data, meta ) {
        return '<input type="text" name='+data.id+' value='+data.value+'>';
    }},

    { "data": null, "defaultContent":'<center><ul class="icons-list"><li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-menu9"></i></a><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">' +
     '<li><a href="#" class="history" ><i class="icon-file-stats"></i> Timeline</a></li>' +
     '<li><a href="#" class="profile" ><i class="icon-user"></i> Profile</a></li>' +
     '<li><a href="#" class="disconnect"><i class=" icon-file-eye"></i> Disconnect </a></li>' +
     '<li><a href="#" class="suspend"><i class=" icon-file-eye"></i> Suspend </a></li>' +
     '</ul> </li> </ul></center>'}
     //{ "data":null,"defaultContent":"" }
    ]
});
});
```